# bluetoothctl in debian 10 pairing poblem

Tags: bluetooth

When I try to pair my RPI Bluetooth with some other Bluetooth it pairs some time and then it is dis-pairing by itself. How can I fix this problem?

My OS is Raspbian 10 buster and the version of Bluez is 5.50

Comment: _"...with other Bluetooth it pair some time then dis-pairing by itself how to fix this problem."_ The sentence is a bit difficult to parse. Could you please rephrase it a little clearly? ---> I edited it, as I understood it best.

Comment: Hi @bluetooth.  Some months ago I tried to pair/connect a couple of Bluetooth devices with my Rpi3B+ and found everything disappointing: difficult/unreliable/intermittent failing to discover/pair/connect the BT devices.  I googled and found no useful help around.  So I gave up, waiting for Rpi4B to come along.  I also bought two more Bluetooth speakers to try.  Now the time has come for me to try again.  I first tried to pair the two BT speakers with my Samsung smart phone and everything went well, implying both BT speakers are working OK. / to continue, ...

Comment: I tried the following with both speakers, (1) Creative, (2) XiaoMi: (a) reboot Rpi4B (important to get repeatable/reliable results), (b) GUI Deskop top right hand corner BT icon to discover/pair the speaker, (c) when paired, click the speaker icon (beside WiFi icon) to check "connection" and adjusting volume, (d) play a mp3 file using VLC media player.  I found that I can always pair and "connect" (VLC to connect to speaker) with the Creative BT speaker.  But for the XiaoMi BT speaker, I can always "pair", but never "connect" (speaker icon always red crossed). / to continue, ...

Comment: So my conclusion is that Rpi4B BT works reliably with Creative speaker but not  XiaoMi or Rapoo.  Creative speaker costs twice of the other two, so I think its  power is perhaps also twice bigger or sensitive.  Anyway, I tried to do more evaluation, I found I could no longer detect nor pair, not to mention connect.  I guessed the Rpi4 chips must had been heated up and became crazy.  So I waited for 20 minutes or and and also added heat sinks to the chips.  Then everything comes back normal again.  My second quick and dirty conclusion is that Rpi4B, if heated up, it will get crazy! :(

Comment: So for now I am only using the Creative Bluetooth speaker which I found very stable and reliable.  Every time I want to use my VLC media player to play music, I do the following: (1) Reboot Rpi4B Raspbian 10 Buster Jul 10, (2) Pair speaker (clicking BlueTooth icon), (3) Connect speaker and adjust volume (clicking speaker icon), (4) Use VLC to play music.  The pairing is smooth, almost detected /pairing smoothly first time, very stable, no disconnecting/dispairing for the 2 hours testing.  I once thought about using an USB BT dongle to replace on board weak BT guy, but too lazy to do it now